# AWS DMS ExpiredToken

Tags: aws-dms

I am using DMS migration tasks to push data from my postgres to redshift. The problem I have is that migration goes well up to some point, but then it fails. The only thing I see in the logs is:
`ExpiredToken: Unable to parse ExceptionName: ExpiredToken Message: The provided token has expired. [1001705]  (transfer_client.cpp:510)`

`Failed to upload file XX to bucket YYY as xxx.csv`

`Failed to write entire file (second trial) [1000722]  (at_universal_fs_object.c:631)`

`Write entire file failed: source = .... open type = 3`

`Failed to add/send file ... Attempting to retry (1/5)`

The job is pushing a 0.5Bil of records and it takes >3 hours.

The result is that just a subset of data is pushed correctly. Other tasks that work shorter/have smaller number of rows complete successfully.

I have no idea what to check next. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like the IAM role used in the process had **Maximum session duration** parameter set to 1 hour. Since the job took longer, the token expired and task couldn't be completed. Increasing the parametr helped. Although I must say it wasn't easy to debug logs from DMS didn't help.